# Wallet Connect not working on Android phone having a Android version greater than 10

Tags: blockchain, dapps, walletconnect

I have integrated the wallet connect on a react native application, The app work perfect on the android phone that has a android version lower or equal to 10, If i run the application on a phone that have a version greater than 10 so it redirect me to the browser and shows me the error 404 not found, Instead when i use the app on a phone that has a android version lesser than 10 so it works fine and pop up the metamask perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/react-native

In order to make your app compatible with Android SDK 29 and newer, edit your AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following code:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="wc"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
```